# send() not deliver all bytes?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, byte, winsock

Why doesn't `send()` in `winsock` guarantee delivery of the all bytes you request?

This is TCP and it's blocking sockets.

Similarly, this happens when non-blocking. How can you guarantee that you send everything?

I've noticed `recv()` does the same.

Answer (score 8):

If it didn't send everything, just call `send` again on the rest. If blocking, you can do it immediately. If non-blocking, you can either wait or use a socket discovery method (like `select` or I/O completion ports). The same goes for `recv`. If you didn't get all you wanted, call `recv` again. This is one of the reasons both `recv` and `send` return the number of bytes sent or received.

The number of bytes you pass to `send` or `recv` is just a limit. It can send less than that (though, unless non-blocking, usually won't). But it can definitely receive less than that. (The OS has no control over how much data it receives or when it receives it.)

TCP is implemented for you. But if you have an application protocol that involves application-level messages, then the application has to implement them. It won't happen by magic. TCP doesn't "glue the bytes together" into a message for you. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, not a message protocol. If you want messages, you have to implement them.

Comment: David, slightly OT but didn't we discuss in comp.protocols.tcp-IP a couple of years ago that actually it does send/buffer all the bytes in blocking mode? On all known platforms?

Comment: @EJP: For TCP, unless interrupted by a signal or an error occurs, every implementation I know of will at least queue all the bytes you pass to `send` in blocking mode and will not return fewer than the number of bytes you ask it to send. (That doesn't mean an implementation can't come out next week that doesn't, but probably a lot of existing code would break on that implementation.)

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is "by design".

You can use an outer loop as shown in this example:

```
int sendBuffer (SOCKET ClientSocket, const char *buf, int len, int flags) 
  {
    int num_left = len;
    int num_sent;
    int err = 0;
    const char *cp = buf;

    while (num_left > 0) 
      {
        num_sent = send(ClientSocket, cp, num_left, flags);

        if (num_sent < 0) 
          {
            err = SOCKET_ERROR;
            break;
          }

        assert(num_sent <= num_left);

        num_left -= num_sent;
        cp += num_sent;
      }

    return (err == SOCKET_ERROR ?  SOCKET_ERROR : len);
  }
```

Comment: 0 bytes sent doesn't mean that the connection has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`send` tells you what it was able to send via its return value.
Loop until `send` has cumulatively sent all the data or returns an error.