# TCP File Transfer - Few bytes error

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I am currently working on a C# program that allows the user to send a file over the network and reassemble it at the other end. It is all working fine apart from a few bytes being misplaced int the destination leaving it as not quite the same file it started as. (Corrupting images for example).
Edit: At least when it's on my computer I noticed that the error can be solved by having the client wait one second before starting to read from the stream, this gives my the idea that the client occasionally gets to the end of the stream and reads something else instead. Any idea how to fix that in a better way than just waiting for a second as with other computers I don't know if that'll work.
The code for my server is as follows:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(13);
        listener.Start();
        FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(loadLocation.Text);//loadLocation being a text box with the file path
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(loadLocation.Text);
        int size = unchecked((int)f.Length);//Get's the file size in Bytes
        int  csize = size / 4096;//Get's the size in chunks of 4kb;

           statusLabel.Text = "Waiting for connection...";
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            statusLabel.Text = "Connection accepted.";
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] byteSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);//Sends the number of bytes to expect over the network
            try
            {
                ns.Write(byteSize, 0, byteSize.Length);
                byte[] temp = new byte[4096];
                for (int i = 0; i < csize; i++)
                {
                    inputStream.Read(temp, 0, 4096);
                    ns.Write(temp, 0, 4096);
                }
                byte[] end = new byte[size % 4096];
                inputStream.Read(end, 0, size % 4096);
                ns.Write(end, 0, size % 4096);
                ns.Close();
                inputStream.Close();
                client.Close();
                done = true;
                statusLabel.Text = "DONE!";
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            }
        listener.Stop();
```

The client code is as follows:

```
try
        {
            FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(saveLocation.Text);
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13);

            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

            byte[] byteTime = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            int bytesRead = ns.Read(byteTime, 0, sizeof(int));
            int size;
            size = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteTime, 0);
            int csize = size / 4096;
            byte[] temp = new byte[4096];
            for (int i = 0; i < csize; i++)
            {
                ns.Read(temp, 0, 4096);
                outputStream.Write(temp, 0, 4096);
            }
            byte[] end = new byte[size % 4096];
            ns.Read(end, 0, size % 4096);
            outputStream.Write(end, 0, size % 4096);
            ns.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            statusLabel.Text = "DONE!";

        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }
```

I know that TCP guarantees order of delivery and as such I have no idea what could be possibly causing the problem with the output file. The other note worthy part is that each time, the corruption is slightly different for example when transferring an image there will be a large mark at a different point on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should take into account, that a `NetworkStream` (and most `TCP sockets` in general) does not necessarily return the full number of bytes originally requested.

Microsoft [writes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the
>   number of bytes specified by the size parameter.

Add an outer loop around your read operations to ensure the buffer is actually filled. Some more error handling would also be advisable.

Perhaps, you can get some inspiration from a similar [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399691/send-not-deliver-all-bytes/14399819#14399819). It shows how such an outer loop can look like.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd up vote your answer if I had more reputation.