# some packets lost in async tcp Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

In my network protocol for my server application, I have 2 bytes at the beginning of each buffer sent containing the length. And the TcpReadCallback method reads the bytes written by BeginReceive until the full buffer has been read. However, using my implementation, packets seem to get lost and sometimes empty buffers are sent to ProcessReceiveBuffer, especially so when I'm sending messages under 5ms apart, and a lot more common when sending over the internet (will happen ever 10 or so seconds with sending ever half second). Is there anyone who can spot what I'm doing wrong in here?

Thanks!

```
private Socket _tcpWorkSocket;
private byte[] _tcpWorkBuffer;
private byte[] _tcpReceiveBuffer;

public void BeginTcpReceive() {
    if (!Connected)
        return;

    _tcpWorkBuffer = new byte[BufferSize]; // 1024
    _tcpWorkSocket.BeginReceive(_tcpWorkBuffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(TcpReadCallback), this);
}

private void TcpReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        if (!Connected)
            return;

        int readBytes = _tcpWorkSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (readBytes > 0) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[readBytes];
            Array.Copy(_tcpWorkBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, readBytes);
            if (User != null)
                User.SessionTimerReset();
            Proccess_Buffer(buffer);
        }
        BeginTcpReceive();
    }
    catch(SocketException ex) {
        Close(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.LogError("{0}: {1}\n{2}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        Close(false);
    }
}

private void Proccess_Buffer(byte[] buffer) {
    if (!Receiving) {
        Receiving = true;
        _tcpPacketLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
        _tcpBytesNeeded = _tcpPacketLength;
        _tcpCurIndex = 0;
        _tcpReceiveBuffer = new byte[_tcpPacketLength];
    }
    int origSize = buffer.Length;
    int copyLength = _tcpBytesNeeded;
    if (_tcpBytesNeeded > BufferSize)
        copyLength = BufferSize;
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, _tcpReceiveBuffer, _tcpCurIndex, copyLength);
    _tcpCurIndex += buffer.Length;
    _tcpBytesNeeded -= buffer.Length;

    if (_tcpBytesNeeded <= 0) {
        Receiving = false;
        ProcessReceiveBuffer(_tcpReceiveBuffer, Protocal.Tcp);
    }

    if (origSize > buffer.Length) {
        // next packet, incase 2 messages are sent in the same packet.
        byte[] nextBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length - origSize ];
        if (nextBuffer.Length > 1) {
            Array.Copy(buffer, origSize , nextBuffer, 0, nextBuffer.Length);
            Proccess_Buffer(nextBuffer);
        }
        else {
            Logger.LogError("Next buffer length split!");
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

First number after "received" is the order it was sent by the client, second is the size. A few packets are being dropped in TCP ever so often, in bursts, when sent over the internet.

```
[17:29:49]: received: 1349, 514
[17:29:50]: received: 1350, 514
[17:29:50]: received: 1351, 514
[17:29:51]: received: 1352, 514
[17:29:51]: received: 1353, 514
[17:29:52]: received: 1355, 514
[17:29:52]: Skipped! expected 1354, got 1355
[17:29:53]: received: 1357, 514
[17:29:53]: Skipped! expected 1356, got 1357
[17:29:54]: received: 1359, 514
[17:29:54]: Skipped! expected 1358, got 1359
[17:29:56]: received: 1362, 514
[17:29:56]: Skipped! expected 1360, got 1362
[17:29:56]: received: 1363, 514
[17:29:57]: received: 1364, 514
```

Comment: You buffer size in the comments is 1024.  Try make larger.  TCP max datagram size ~1500 bytes max.  Larger messages are broken into smaller sizes under 1500.  Routers and PCs can break the 1500 into smaller pieces.  You can also get a keep alive message with 0 bytes of data.  Your code has to be able to handle all these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to network congestion, it can happen that `EndReceive` does not receive the full message in one go. Therefore `TcpReadCallback` should repeat the read operation until no more bytes are received.

Here is a related [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b(v=vs.110).aspx) which demonstrates the point:

```
public static void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar){
    StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket s = so.workSocket;

    int read = s.EndReceive(ar);

    if (read > 0) {
            so.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, read));
            s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                     new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback), so);
    }
    else{
         if (so.sb.Length > 1) {
              //All of the data has been read, so displays it to the console
              string strContent;
              strContent = so.sb.ToString();
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0} byte from socket" + 
                               "data = {1} ", strContent.Length, strContent));
         }
         s.Close();
    }
}
```

A similar effect in the basic `tcp socket` `send()` and `recv()` calls on operating system level is discussed in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399691/send-not-deliver-all-bytes/14399819#14399819).

Comment: It already attempts to do this. _tcpBytesNeeded is set to the length of the message (sent at the beginning of every message), and is decreased by the length of the received buffer. If it's greater than 0 after decreasing it, then the next TcpReadCallback is applied to that message.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using the implementation from https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking