# C# Socket Programming Mixed data after a while

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, networkstream

I use socket programming with TCPClient and NetworkStream .

My data mixed up after a while that working ever 10 seconds.

What is your idea ???

```
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
var dataRec = new byte[bufferSize];
var result = stream.Read(dataRec, 0, dataRec.Length);
var strResv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataRec, 0, result);
```

Should I use the Async functions?

My data size per request is 100KB

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Why do you mean "mixed data"? Remember it's a stream, and a packet doesn't conform to any kind of idea about a "message", so a single `Read` might net you the end of one message and the start of the next, etc.

Comment: I do not get an error. For example, I get a special form of data But it does deform at Sometimes. I test with Hercules app (Socket Tester) . My data is  
healthy and work correctly but my code don't work.

Comment: "For example, I get a special form of data But it does deform at Sometimes." - I'm still not clear on what "deform" means in this case. A concrete example would be best. Also, since you're using `Encoding.ASCII`, I have to ask - is your data ASCII? For example こんにちは is not ASCII, so I couldn't use ASCII encoding to convert to/from bytes.

Comment: Excuse me , it's better to I say : "My received data is displaced"

Comment: So my first comment is correct then?

Comment: Thanks,Your comment look correct but What exactly should I do?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402731/socket-beginreceive-merging-tcp-packets). Personally I would write 2-4 bytes before each method indicating the size of the forthcoming message, and then you can process each message in the stream in turn.

Comment: Do not assume that the data is received as sent. Due to network congestion, the data packets might be split. Therefore, it can take multiple reads to receive the full packet. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666806/some-packets-lost-in-async-tcp-socket/41666945#41666945).

Comment: It's work. I remove the stream class and just use socket class for send and receive