# tcp send and recv: always in loops?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

What are the best practices when sending (or writing) and recving (or reading) to/from a TCP socket ?

Assume usual blocking I/O on sockets. From what I understand :

- writing (sending) should be fine without a loop, because it will block if the write buffer of the socket is full, so something like

  ```c
  if ((nbytes_w = write(sock, buf, nb)) < nb)
       /* something bad happened : error or interrupted by signal */
  ```

  should always be correct ?
- on the other hand, there is no guaranty that one will read a full message, so one should read with

  ```c
  while ((nbytes_r = read(sock, buf, MAX)) > 0) {
      /* do something with these bytes */
      /* break if encounter specific application protocol end of message flag
         or total number of bytes was known from previous message
         and/or application protocol header */
  }
  ```

Am I correct ? Or is there some "small message size" or other conditions allowing to read safely outside a loop ?

I am confused because I have seen examples of "naked reads", for instance in Tanenbaum-Wetherall:

```c
read(sa, buf, BUF_SIZE); /* read file name in socket */
```

Comment: For sufficiently small buffers people tent to assume that the chances of receiving the packet in multiple chunks is too low to worry about. Don't be one of them. ;)

Comment: Check this answer re send/write: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399717/1076479. Summarizing, most/all implementations *will* block on send, but none of the implementations' specifications really *guarantee* it. Since it would not be wrong for an implementation to return a short write, your best bet is to assume it might happen. And since it is not difficult to implement the loop, you should just do it. This will give you maximum portability in respect to both platforms and transport mechanisms.

Comment: And BTW your `write` statement above is missing necessary parentheses to do what you intend. It should be `if ((nbytes_w = write(sock, buf, nb)) < nb)`

Comment: @GilHamilton Thank you for the typo, it's edited. Thank you. As for writing in loops, I guess you are right, but I still don't get it. Why bother implementing a blocking write in the first place if you can't count on it ?

Comment: The blocking write essentially guarantees that *some* progress will occur in the system call (or an error will be returned). A non-blocking write alternative would lead your program to (potentially) spin, wasting CPU cycles and accomplishing nothing, until progress could be made. Hence, it makes the programming paradigm far simpler: no need to use `select` or other elaborate mechanisms to implement a simple sequential process.

Comment: It *would* be simpler for the application programmer if the OS guaranteed that the entire `send` would complete before returning. And, in practice, you can probably count on it. I think it's not guaranteed because the original designers did not want to constrain future implementations. (Also IMO it's consistent with general OS philosophy: consider attempting to write a 16G block to a disk file, but the disk became full during the write. The natural way to handle this is to return bytes successfully written. The caller can then retry the write with remaining bytes to discover the error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must loop on the receive

Once a week I answer a question where someones TCP app stops working for this very reason.  The real killer is that they developped the client and server on the same machine, so they get loopback connection. Almost all the time a loopback will receive the send messages in the same blocks as they were sent. This makes it look like the code is correct.

The really big challenge is that this means you need to know before the loop how big the message is that you are going to receive. Possibilities

- send a fixed length length (ie you know its , say, 4 bytes) first.
- have a recognizable end sequence (like the double crlf at the end of an HTTP request.
- Have a fixed size message

I would always have a 'pull the next n bytes' function.

Writing should loop too, but that easy, its just a matter of looping.

Comment: You must loop the send, too. `send()` can take fewer bytes than requested, just like `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested. Both functions return the actual number of bytes accepted/received. Pay attention to that value.

Comment: "*the double crlf at the end of an HTTP request*" - HTTP messages are not ended by a double-crlf. Only the HEADERS are, but the BODY is not.

Comment: @pm100 Thank you very much. Could you please give references (RFCs or man pages) about writing needing loops ? It does not make sense to me to implement a blocking write if there is no guaranty that everything will be written. Is it ok on Unix systems ?

Comment: @Villetaneuse https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html  - read the 'return value' comments

Comment: @pm100 Thank you. But then the examples of incomplete writes in this man page are very specific. When writing to a socket can it happen only when interrupted by a signal ? Sorry if this looks pedantic but I would like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Villetaneuse check out read_n and write_n here https://github.com/fpagliughi/sockpp/blob/master/src/stream_socket.cpp